# execl not working when the program in which it's defined is passed as argument

Tags: c, linux, exec

Below code is saved as abc.c on linux. It's execl() is not working in the code below. Could anybody please explain why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
int main()
{
   int r;
   char ch;
   printf("Enter any character");
   scanf(" %c",&ch);
   printf("%c",ch);
   r=execl("abc",NULL);
   printf("r = %d",r);
   return 0;
}
```

r = -1 coming as output. Please explain

Thanks :)

Comment: Change to `execl("./abc", (char*)NULL);` and _check_ `errno` to determine the reason for failure.

Comment: I tried ./abc , even this is not working. NULL is needed to be typecasted?? I haven't done so in other programs ever. Ok I will check for the error no. Thanks

Comment: From [`execl`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl): _The list of arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer, and, since these are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL._

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note:

1. When you're calling a function like this that returns an error, examine `errno` to see what it was (e.g. `printf("r = %d   errno = %d",r,errno);`
2. The most likely cause is that `execl` cannot find the program `abc` -- it doesn't look on the path, and *probably* doesn't look in the current directory.  In the first instance, try using the full path (e.g. `execl( "/usr/me/abc", NULL );`
3. It probably won't stop it working, but it's traditional to pass the name of the program as the first argument (so, `execl( "/usr/me/abc", "/usr/me/abc", NULL );`
4. If you *do* get `execl` to work, it won't return to your code to tell you that it did so.